# How does a two's complement number overflow?

Tags: binary

The problem is to convert $32$ to $6$-bit two's complement or note that the range would overflow.

For $32$, I have: $100000$.

How does this overflow? Is it because the 1 means negative, so it would be $0100000$ but the space cannot accommodate this? But the notes say the max positive number is $2^5 - 1 = 31$.

Comment: The range you want to cover with 6 bits is from $-2^5$ to $2^5-1$, is it?

Comment: Where does the power 5 come from?

Comment: Well, 5 = 6-1. Just like 32-bit system stores numbers from $-2^{31}$ to $2^{31}-1$.

Comment: My question was about following: with 6 bits you can either store numbers in range $[−2^5, 2^5−1]$, or numbers in range $[0,2^6-1]$, or technically speaking you can store an element from a fixed set with $2^6$ elements. So the question if the range would overflow is a bit weird without clarification, what your range is.

Comment: @mike239x: the question says that the representation is 6-bit two's complement, so the range is $-2^5$ to $2^5-1$. The OP's explanation for the overflow is essentially correct: $32_{10} = 100000_{2}$ and $100000$ is interpreted as $-32_{10}$ in 6-bit two's complement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, in twos complement the first bit represents the sign and the rest of the bits represent the number.  Writing $32_{10}=100\ 000_2$ is not legal in twos complement as the leading bit being $1$ represents a negative number and $32_{10}$ is not negative.  In $6$ bit twos complement the largest positive number you can represent is $31_{10}=011\ 111$.  As you count down you get to $)_{10}=000\ 000$, then roll over to $-1_{10}=111\ 111$.  As you keep counting down you finally get to $-32_{10}=100\ 000$, which is the most negative number you can represent.  Your proposed representation of $32_{10}=100\ 000$ would be read as $-32_{10}$